# How to display only current time using DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance() in android

Tags: java, android, date-format, date-formatting

I am new to android. In android I want to display only current time in a textview in the format hh:mm am/pm (eg: 3:02 PM) I use the following code.

`String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        tv.setText(currentDateTimeString);`

It gives the current date,month,year and time.But i need to get only the current time from this. Is there any way to display only time? Can anyone help me to get the time without date from the above code.[using DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()]

Comment: do u want to display current time into  text view or edit text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try following code

```
     Date d=new Date();
     SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
     String currentDateTimeString = sdf.format(d);
     tv.setText(currentDateTimeString);
```

Comment: Is this 24hr time or 12hr?

Comment: 12 hr... that's why I used 'a' for am/pm

Answer (score 8):

> It gives the current date, month, year and time, but 
>   I need to get only the current time from this.

If you want to do this **and** respect the users preferences (e.g. 12 vs 24 hour clock) then continue to use `DateFormat`, only like so:

```
DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date());
```

Comment: Sorry, I've downvoted this answer by mistake. Actually, it's the only correct answer.

Comment: @AlexeyVMP thanks, I've edited so you should be able to remove downvote or upvote now.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<DigitalClock
        android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DigitalClock" />
```

this is basic control of android.

Answer (score 0):

```
 startTime = ""+System.currentTimeMillis();
                    StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(startTime.trim());
                    String date = tk.nextToken();  
                    String time = tk.nextToken();

                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                    SimpleDateFormat sdfs = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                    Date dt;
                    try {    
                        dt = sdf.parse(time);
                        System.out.println("Time Display: " + sdfs.format(dt)); // <-- I got result here
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:SS").format(new Date()));
```

Android Time picker component follow the link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

for more info

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

> It gives the current date,month,year and time.But i need to get only
> the current time from this.

The `java.util.Date` object is not a real Date-Time object like the [modern Date-Time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the Date-Time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the Date-Time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it e.g.

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

In order to get just the time, you just need to replace (a) `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` with `hh:mm a` and (b) `America/New_York` with the applicable timezone.

However, the `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern API:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Replace JVM's timezone i.e. ZoneId.systemDefault() with the applicable
        // timezone e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        // Print the default format i.e. the value of time.toString()
        System.out.println(time);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formattedTime = dtf.format(time); // Alternatively, time.format(dtf)
        System.out.println(formattedTime);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
11:59:07.443868
11:59 AM
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>